# Play framework inconsistent build

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm getting the following stack trace first time i run
`activator run`

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7!commons-compress.jar (1ms)
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /activator-dist-1.3.9/repository/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.7/jars/commons-compress.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.tukaani#xz;1.4!xz.jar (0ms)
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /activator-dist-1.3.9/repository/org.tukaani/xz/1.4/jars/xz.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7!commons-compress.jar
[warn]  :: org.tukaani#xz;1.4!xz.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7!commons-compress.jar
download failed: org.tukaani#xz;1.4!xz.jar
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
```

[Full trace here](http://pastebin.com/58yKBN21)

Sometimes I get the chance to press `retry` and when I do it succeeds.
I'm building this with docker and would want it to work every time.

here are my configs

**build.sbt**

```
name := """swsupplymonitor"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.4.0" % "test",
  javaJdbc
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

**build.properties**

```
#Activator-generated Properties
#Tue Jul 07 09:30:59 CEST 2015
template.uuid=f5aa99a5-66e6-4ba6-abda-852c14da8938
sbt.version=0.13.8
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
logLevel := Level.Warn


// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")
```

and this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
MAINTAINER Nils Eriksson
ENV UPDATED_AT=2016-03-19

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN curl -o ./activator.zip http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.9/typesafe-activator-1.3.9.zip
RUN unzip activator.zip -d / && rm activator.zip && chmod a+x /activator-dist-1.3.9/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:/activator-dist-1.3.9/bin

EXPOSE 9000 8888
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ .

CMD ["activator", "run"]
```

which i run with this command

```
docker run -di -v $(pwd):/app:rw -p $PORT:9000 --name beacon-backend --link db:db beacon-backend
```

Comment: Looking at the error message, I had the impression that you are `offline` since no remote repository was used to locate the dependencies. Are you sure docker has internet access when starting?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check your connection. The unresolved dependency download is because while resolving your dependencies sbt cannot connect to remote repositories to download them.

if you're connecting thorough a firewall also check that this repos are allowed.

Answer (score -1):

set sbt.version=0.13.11 in build.properties.